# How to resize Window to dimension in VIew Controller for a OSX app?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm fairly new to Mac OSX Apps, but I'm trying to build an app with no status bar, and the dimensions are smaller. So what I did in my AppDelegate.m is:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
  {
    self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];
    [self.window setOpaque:NO];
    [self.window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    self.mainViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
 }
```

Now, what I really want to do, is to get my window to look like, what I've built in my interface builder (can't post pictures yet). I've tried shutting off all the autosizing elements but when I run the simulator I get a clipped version of my interface (the size changes every run). It seem like the frame size is getting miscalculated, but I've done everything from the interface builder. I can programmatically set the shapes of the view, but is there a way to shut off all resizing and simply portray the xib file as what I see in the interface builder?

Comment: So your question is how to stop `NSWindow` resizing?

Comment: pretty much, but i was wondering if there was an option beside putting something like:
[window setMinSize:size]

in the app delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could approach this problem.

1. You add an AutoresizingMask to your ViewController:

   `[self.mainViewController setAutoresizingMask:NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeigt];`
2. You disable window resizing in the Interface builder like by setting its minimum and maximum size. This can also be done in code.

[image]

[image]

Edit: Thanks to  trojanfoe for pointing out that you can also uncheck Resize in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: And unckeck the "Resize" Window option?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resize your window programatically. Here's how:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSRect frame;
    frame.size.height = 200;
    frame.size.width = 200;
    [window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}
```